# NoSuchMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.remote.CommandInfo.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/openqa/selenium/remote/HttpVerb;)V

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selendroid

i'm trying to run selendroid web for practice but i'm getting errors even i update selenium version (2.48.2) and set all paths correctly.

below is my code and i'm getting this error.

Please help me...

NoSuchMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.remote.CommandInfo.(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/openqa/selenium/remote/HttpVerb;)V

```
 package com.guru.test;

 import io.selendroid.SelendroidCapabilities;
  import io.selendroid.SelendroidDriver;

  import org.openqa.selenium.By;
  import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
 import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
 import org.testng.annotations.AfterSuite;
 import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;
  import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class testWeb {

public WebDriver driver;

@BeforeSuite
public void setUp() throws Exception
{
    DesiredCapabilities caps = SelendroidCapabilities.android();        
    driver = new SelendroidDriver(caps);
}

@Test
public void WebSiteTest() throws Exception
{
    driver.get("http://google.com");
    WebElement searchQuery = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
    searchQuery.click();
    searchQuery.sendKeys("Test");
    WebElement submit = driver.findElement(By.name("btnG"));
    submit.click();
}

@AfterSuite
public void tearDown() throws Exception{
    driver.quit();
}

 }
```

Comment: Did you google the error? What did you find? Please show what you have tried and what the result was.

Comment: Which jars do you have in classpath ?

Comment: Including the whole stack trace, or at least the first few lines would be helpful.

Comment: selendroid-client-0.10.0.jar

Comment: i googled it i couldn't find answer...

Comment: @BhushanPatil can you help me...

Comment: @Vzwpowertestverizon123 Sorry I was on vacation. Did solve this issue ?

Comment: @BhushanPatil no not at all please help me

Comment: @Vzwpowertestverizon123 I think you have mixed up selenium and selendroid jars. selendroid-standalone + selendroid-client should be enough for this.

Comment: @BhushanPatil thanks it works!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have mixed up selenium and selendroid jars. **selendroid-standalone** + **selendroid-client** should be enough for this.